# How to make dynamic HTMLtable cell clickable?

Tags: asp.net, mouseclick-event, dynamic-tables

I have a dynamic Htmltable that contains several cells and i need to make each cell clickable

```
row = new HtmlTableRow();
for (int j = 1; j <= column_days; j++)
{
    label = new Label() { ID = "lbl"+j.ToString() };
    label.Text = label.ID;
    cell = new HtmlTableCell();                  
    row.Cells.Add(cell);

}
table1.Rows.Add(row);
```

After i generated this on PageLoad, i need to make each cell clickable.
Any idea?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: First step is to figure out how you would do it if it were plain HTML. Then figure out how to make ASP.NET generate the same HTML.